# ubuntu + how to install the patch command

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

Please advice how to install the patch command on Ubuntu Linux

I download the following file , patch_2.6-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ( from site - 
http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/patch )

But not clearly how to install it?

I tried by ./patch_2.6-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb , ( but I get errors )

Please advice how to install the pkg patch_2.6-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
In order to use thepatch command on my unbuntu linux

Answer (score 7):

This website tells you that the package is in the repository. You should not download the package from the website to install it.

You should use your package manager :

```
sudo apt-get install patch
```

Comment: the problem is that I not connected to the network , I guess this will dowload the pkg from network

Comment: @Eytan Yes it downloads the package (you can also use the install cd as repository, but I don't know what's on it). In that case use dpkg.

Answer (score 4):

".deb" files are not executable binaries. Use `dpkg` command to install your package :

```
dpkg -i your_package.deb
```

Answer (score -1):

since your patch is tar.gz a simple way to install is to get alien

```
sudo apt-get install alien
```

then turn tar.gz into deb

```
sudo alien -k file.tar.gz
```

Comment: "since your patch is `tar.gz`" why do get information? The OP clearly indicates a downloaded a `.deb` file of the patch command.